# How to use batchWriteItem on Appsync with Resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

I have a problem with Appsync, Dynamodb on Amazon
So I want to delete multi rows on table. I used batchWriteItem but it showed "operation unsuportted it" on Resolver
So how to use batchWriteItem for delete multi rows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Batch operations with DynamoDB resolvers in AWS AppSync are:

- BatchPutItem
- BatchGetItem
- BatchDeleteItem

This will also require a `"tables"` key in your resolver configuration where you can perform these operations against one or multiple tables in a single GraphQL query or mutation.

With a DynamoDB data source you'll also find these listed in the sample templates in the console.

You can find an in-depth tutorial here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html